# Type conversion - in c?

Tags: c, pointers, types, type-conversion

```c
float f_var = 1.5F; 
long *l_ptr = (long *)&f_var;
```

What is the difference between above statement and below  statement?

```c
double *d_ptr = (double *)l_ptr;
```

My doubt is what makes the difference using "&" in the above statement .

Can you give little example to solve my doubt?

Comment: Should the last line be `double *d_ptr = (double *)&f_var;` ? The two lines are so different (both syntactically and semantically) that it's difficult to guess what explanation you are looking for.

Comment: My doubt is what is  the main difference using & in the above f_var

Comment: The last line is based on the variable in the previous one, so I can't make any sense of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is the address-of operator. It returns the address of the variable that stores a certain value. Normally, one would do `float *f_ptr = &f_var;` to get a float pointer to a value of type float. If you instead use `long *l_ptr = (long *)&f_var;` you get a pointer of type `long*` pointing to the same variable (which is still a float). This is dangerous and will rarely give the expected result, for two reasons: a) `sizeof(long)` might be larger than `sizeof(float)`, causing an access to `l_ptr` to result in undefined behavior. b) Reading the value with `long l = *l_ptr` will be mostly useless, since a float is not a long, and no value conversion took place. The value of l will not be the integer part of the float, as you might expect.

This `double *d_ptr = (double *)l_ptr;` has similar problems: While now, both sides are pointers, interpreting a pointer to a long as a pointer to double is only useful in very rare cases (e.g. when working with unions). And double is now for certain longer than float, so doing `double d = *d_ptr` *will* result in undefined behavior.

Bottom line: Neither of these instructions are useful, at least certainly not in beginners code.

Comment: Undefined behavior results from accessing a `float` via a pointer to `long` regardless of the relative sizes of those types.  This is among the consequences of the so-called "strict aliasing rule". In any case, however, you are quite right that no conversion of the pointed-to value is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

This `long *l_ptr = (long *)&f_var;` takes the address of a `float` variable and uses it as a pointer to an integer variable. This will result in extremely weird integer values being read if that pointer is dereferenced.

This `double *d_ptr = (double *)l_ptr;` uses that pointer to a `float` variable (which is seen as a pointer to an integer variable) as a pointer to a `double` variable, which among other things is wider than a `float`. This, if dereferenced, will result in extremely weird `double` values, which include the interpretation of incorrectly accessed memory and all kinds of broken rules.

Do not do either unless you have neglected to mention a lot of in-depth knowledge about neighbouring memory and environment specific type handling - and you would still end up with undefined behaviour.

Comment: We had an almost equal idea :-)

Comment: Do not do either unless you like undefined behavior bugs.